# Error: "invalid use of incomplete type" and "forward declaration"

Tags: c++

I have the following errors trying to use a TFT library function inside my library. My library uses the pointer to an instance of the TFT library in the constructor, as well described there:

[Basic C++ programming, how to pass constructor argument into class?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18974/19684)

The errors are:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class TFT'
_TFTscreen->background(0, 0, 0);

error: forward declaration of 'class TFT'
class TFT;
```

*MESmenu.h:*

```
#ifndef _MESMENU_H_
#define _MESMENU_H_

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

class TFT;

class MESmenu{
public:
  MESmenu(TFT* pTFT) : _TFTscreen(pTFT) {};
  void start();
  void execute();
private:
  TFT* _TFTscreen;
};

#endif
```

*MESmenu.cpp:*

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "MESmenu.h"

void MESmenu::start(){
  _TFTscreen->background(0, 0, 0);
  _TFTscreen->text("starting menu...", 0, 0);
  //...
}

void MESmenu::execute(){
   //some code...  
}
```

The *Arduino sketch* is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TFT.h>  // Arduino LCD library
#include <MESmenu.h>  // my library

// --------- TFT LCD ---------
// pin definition for the due
#define sd_cs  7
#define lcd_cs 10
#define dc     9
#define rst    8
TFT TFTscreen = TFT(lcd_cs, dc, rst);

// MES menu class
MESmenu *mainMenu = new MESmenu(&TFTscreen);

void setup() {
  // initialize TFT
  TFTscreen.begin();
  TFTscreen.background(0, 0, 0);
  // set the stroke color to white
  TFTscreen.stroke(255,255,255);
  TFTscreen.fill(255,255,255);
  TFTscreen.setTextSize(2);
  TFTscreen.text("TEST", 0, 0);

  // Start menu
  mainMenu->start();
}

void loop () {
  mainMenu->execute();      
}
```

The problem is related to the function:

```
_TFTscreen->background(0, 0, 0);
```

inside the MESmenu::start() in the .cpp file.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by **frarugi87** I've updated the question with the details of .h and .cpp files.
Those file are in the Arduino\libraries\MESmenu folder.

I try to change

```
class TFT;
```

with

```
#include <TFT.h>
```

and removed the #include  from the main arduino sketch.

This leads to the following errors:

```
libraries\MESmenu\MESmenu.cpp.o: In function `Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: multiple definition of `Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
sketch\test_MESmenu_lib.ino.cpp.o:D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: first defined here

libraries\MESmenu\MESmenu.cpp.o: In function `Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: multiple definition of `PImage::read16(SDLib::File)'
sketch\test_MESmenu_lib.ino.cpp.o:D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/PImage.h:17: first defined here

libraries\MESmenu\MESmenu.cpp.o: In function `Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: multiple definition of `PImage::read32(SDLib::File)'
sketch\test_MESmenu_lib.ino.cpp.o:D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/PImage.h:17: first defined here

libraries\MESmenu\MESmenu.cpp.o: In function `Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: multiple definition of `PImage::loadImage(char const*)'
sketch\test_MESmenu_lib.ino.cpp.o:D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/PImage.h:17: first defined here
```

Comment: Please add the actual source code that gives the problem. It looks like you have forgot to include the TFT header file in the menu source file.

Comment: The posted code is almoste complete.
I have the MESmenu.cpp file that contais:

    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include "MESmenu.h"
    
    void MESmenu::execute(){
      _TFTscreen->background(0, 0, 0); 
    }

And this give me the error.
If I put the code of the function "execute" in the .h file it works.
If the code is in the .cpp file I got the error.

I cannot include the TFT.h library in the .h or .ccp files, becouse it leads to "multiple definition"

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
class TFT;
```

to

```
#include <TFT.h>
```

Then you can remove the `#include <TFT.h>` from the main arduino sketch.

Moreover you should at least write a piece of code to make the compiler include your library just once; this is the usual way to do it:

```
#ifndef _MESMENU_H_
#define _MESMENU_H_

#include <SPI.h>

...
the rest of your library
...

  TFT* _TFTscreen;
}

#endif
```

`_MESMENU_H_` is any unique string (usually the filename is used, remembering that you can't put spaces or other punctuation marks except the underscore). And you should put it only in the header file (*.h or *.hpp), not in the source (*.c or *.cpp or *.ino)

EDIT:

The additional info lead me to analyze the library and.. there are problems with the library. Particularly the file `TFT/src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h` has a big problem: it has the code for the functions.

To fix it, you have to modify the library.

Go into the folder `TFT/src/utility/` and make a copy of `Adafruit_GFX.h`, calling it `PImage.cpp`.

Open `Adafruit_GFX.h` and delete everything between line 227 and line 370. This means that from

```
bool useFill;
};

#if defined(__SD_H__)  // Arduino SD library

#define BUFFPIXEL 20

void Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage & img, uint16_t x, uint16_t y) {

...

  return PImage(bmpFile, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, bmpDepth, bmpImageoffset, rowSize, flip);
}

#endif

#endif // _ADAFRUIT_GFX_H
```

it should become

```
bool useFill;
};

#endif // _ADAFRUIT_GFX_H
```

Having done this, open `PImage.cpp` and delete everything above line 227, then delete the function `Adafruit_GFX::image` and the last `endif` and add, at the beginning, `#include Adafruit_GFX.h`. This means that the file should look like

```
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"

#if defined(__SD_H__)  // Arduino SD library

#define BUFFPIXEL 20

// These read 16- and 32-bit types from the SD card file.
// BMP data is stored little-endian, Arduino is little-endian too.
// May need to reverse subscript order if porting elsewhere.

uint16_t PImage::read16(File f) {

...  

  return PImage(bmpFile, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, bmpDepth, bmpImageoffset, rowSize, flip);
}

#endif
```

Then try to compile again the program

BTW: the source I looked at is at [this page](http://bitsbytesnibble.com/indefero/p/builduinok5/source/tree/master/libraries/TFT/src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h).

Comment: I try with your suggestion, but now I got "multiple definition" releated to Adafruit_GFX.h that is included in the TFT library. Do you think that the problem could be in the TFT library itself?

Comment: @DavideTagliafierro multiple definitions of what?

Comment: `libraries\MESmenu\MESmenu.cpp.o: In function 'Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)':`

`D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: multiple definition of 'Adafruit_GFX::image(PImage&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'`

`sketch\test_MESmenu.ino.cpp.o:D:\Software\arduino-1.6.7\libraries\TFT\src/utility/Adafruit_GFX.h:231: first defined here`

Comment: Ok, and where is MESmenu.cpp? Can you post the whole modified files in the question? Or at least the ino, mesmenu.h and mesmenu.cpp

Comment: Question updated with more details. I try to move all the functions from the .cpp file to the .h file it works (not tested on the board, but it compiles). I still doesn't understand why.

Comment: @DavideTagliafierro Modified the answer; it looks like the library is broken ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I tried to modify the library following your indications, but I got even more "multiple definition" than before. I think that the TFT library needs more changes... I ended up moving all the functions of my MESmenu library to the .h file and delete the .cpp file.
I was stuck since a long time on that and in one day you help me getting out. Thanks.

Comment: @DavideTagliafierro Glad you made it. Anyway you should not include the cpp file too; and the common rule is thaty you should only include h files, and in h files you should never define variables (only declare them - as external, of course) nor implement functions outside class definition; these should be performed in cpp or ino files..